# Function accessing private member of a class in same file

Tags: kotlin, visibility, private

I have a function that relies on a property that is initialized at class load time. Currently, it is written like this:

```
object MyObj {
    private val myPrivateProperty = someInitializingStuff();

    fun foo(bar: String) {
        doSomethingWith(bar, myPrivateProperty)
    }
}
```

However, I would prefer if it could be called using the simpler syntax `foo(bar)` instead of `MyObj.foo(bar)`. So I thought I could take it out of the object declaration, like this:

```
object MyObj {
    private val myPrivateProperty = someInitializingStuff();
}

fun foo(bar: String) {
    doSomethingWith(bar, MyObj.myPrivateProperty)
}
```

I was hoping that `foo` would still be able to access `myPrivateProperty` because it's in the same source file, but unfortunately it's not accessible. I don't want to make it `internal` because then my colleagues would be able to access it from their own classes, but I want this to be only accessible to functions declared in this source file only.

If I were writing this in C++, I would have defined `myPrivateProperty` as a static local variable inside the function body, but this is not possible in Kotlin.

Is there another way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you don't want this property to be private to the object because you want to use it in another function. So you should declare it `private` but at the file level (top level) instead. You don't have to store this variable in an object if you don't need to:

```kotlin
private val myPrivateProperty = someInitializingStuff();

fun foo(bar: String) {
    doSomethingWith(bar, myPrivateProperty)
}
```

Another option is to make the object itself private to the file, but the property in the object can be public:

```kotlin
private object MyObj {
    val myPrivateProperty = someInitializingStuff();
}

fun foo(bar: String) {
    doSomethingWith(bar, MyObj.myPrivateProperty)
}
```

However, I would find that pretty odd, because it doesn't seem that using an object is justified here. If it is (for instance because you want to expose other properties from it publicly), then I guess you should put that private variable outside the object as shown in the first option.